# Why is ActiveRecord incorrectly translating SQL command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, will-paginate, active-record-query

I believe that`ActiveRecord::Querying` is screwing up the translation of postgresql commands. The results are returning a different column then what I would expect. Can anybody help me figure out why?

**THIS WORKS (POSTGRES)**

```
SELECT 
quick_tests.id, quick_tests.status, name, 
started_at, array_agg(quick_test_agents.agent_id) as quick_test_agent_ids
FROM quick_tests
JOIN quick_test_agents ON quick_tests.id = quick_test_agents.quick_test_id
GROUP BY quick_tests.id
ORDER BY quick_tests.id desc;
```

**I am trying to paginate all QuickTests by doing this: (quick_test to quick_test_agent is one to many)**

```
tests = QuickTest.paginate :select => 'quick_tests.id,
                                       quick_tests.name,
                                       quick_tests.status,
                                       quick_tests.started_at,
                  array_agg(quick_test_agents.agent_id) as quick_test_agent_ids',
                           :page => current_page,
                           :per_page => page_size,
                           :joins => :quick_test_agent,
                           :group => 'quick_tests.id',
```

**Now the problem is that QuickTest.paginate is not return quick_test_agents.agent_id, it is returning quick_test_agents.id.**

Looking at the log print out, it seems that it is being translated incorrectly:

```
QuickTest Load (57.6ms)  SELECT quick_tests.id, quick_tests.name, quick_tests.status,
 quick_tests.started_at, array_agg(quick_test_agents.agent_id) as quick_test_agent_ids FROM "quick_tests" INNER JOIN "quick_test_agents" ON "quick_test_agents"."quick_test_id" = "quick_tests"."id" 
DEBUG    SQL (70.2ms)  SELECT "quick_test_agents".id FROM "quick_test_agents" WHERE "quick_test_agents"."quick_test_id" = 889
DEBUG    SQL (66.4ms)  SELECT "quick_test_agents".id FROM "quick_test_agents" WHERE "quick_test_agents"."quick_test_id" = 885
DEBUG    SQL (58.3ms)  SELECT "quick_test_agents".id FROM "quick_test_agents" WHERE "quick_test_agents"."quick_test_id" = 883
DEBUG    SQL (56.5ms)  SELECT "quick_test_agents".id FROM "quick_test_agents" WHERE "quick_test_agents"."quick_test_id" = 882
DEBUG    SQL (52.4ms)  SELECT "quick_test_agents".id FROM "quick_test_agents" WHERE "quick_test_agents"."quick_test_id" = 881
DEBUG    SQL (54.6ms)  SELECT "quick_test_agents".id FROM "quick_test_agents" WHERE  "quick_test_agents"."quick_test_id" = 880
DEBUG    SQL (52.6ms)  SELECT "quick_test_agents".id FROM "quick_test_agents" WHERE "quick_test_agents"."quick_test_id" = 879
```

**It should be selecting quick_test_agents.agent_id**

```
SELECT "quick_test_agents".agent_id FROM "quick_test_agents"...
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Or a way to do this is ActiveRecord before paginate, like QuickTest.all(:join =>..., :select =>... blah blah).paginate(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is with aliasing!**

This statement aliases the array aggregation column as quick_test_agent_ids:

```
array_agg(quick_test_agents.agent_id) as quick_test_agent_ids
```

Now, this works in postgres but in ActiveRecord this is getting screwed up. Somehow the alias `quick_test_agent_ids' is causing ActiveRecord to believe it's actually looking for quick_test_agents.id.

If I change the alias statement it works:

```
    array_agg(quick_test_agents.agent_id) as quick_testSSS_agent_ids
    array_agg(quick_test_agents.agent_id) as agent_ids
```

**TL;DR**

Be careful with alias names, they might screw you up